# I need help with this void function in C language.?

Tags: c

```
void insert(int* h, int* n)
{
    printf("give numbers");

    scanf("%d %d", h, n);
}
```

This is the void function I made. This function is suppose to give me the height(h) and the number of hits(n) the ball hits the ground. These numbers are imported by a user.

If the function above is correct, how do I call it?

Answer (score 6):

You can call it as follows:

```
int h;
int n;
insert(&h, &n);
```

Where the `&` means "take the address of".

**But be careful: Your function has NO error-handling for erroneous user-input.**

Answer (score 2):

You can call it in two ways:

```
// Method 1
int h, n;
insert(&h, &n);

// Method 2 (if you need to return the pointers or anything else weird for some reason
// I think this is useful in some cases when you are using a library that requires you
// to pass in heap-allocated memory
int *h = malloc(sizeof(int));
int *n = malloc(sizeof(int));
if(h == NULL || n == NULL)
     exit(1);

insert(h, n);

// Stuff

free(h);
free(n);
h = n = NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
insert(&h, &n)
```

The & operator gets the address of the variables (a pointer to it), and then passes those pointers to the function.  Scanf then uses those points as places to write the values the user enters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what your what your code should look like:

```
   #include <stdio.h>

   void insert(int*, int*)

   int main()
   {
      int n, h;
      insert(&h, &n);

      return 0;
   }
   void insert(int* h, int* n)
   {
       printf("give numbers");

       scanf("%d %d", h, n);
   }
```

However like @Oli your program would break if I input a, 3.5, or anything not an int.

Comment: @monadic I missing the prototype and the preprocessor, I assume he know that much.

Answer (score 0):

It's mostly correct, but that `printf()` isn't guaranteed to be shown. `stdout` may be line buffered, so you would need to issue a `fflush()`.